# wlan0 goes down when eth0 not used

Tags: wireless-networking

I have the Wheezy build loaded on my Pi.  I have my wired ethernet configured with a static IP and I have done the same thing with the wlan.  When the wired is being used the wifi comes up and works.  However when I disconnect the wired cable so I can use the Pi via the wifi it stops functioning.

Have I set up the interfaces file incorrectly?  It seems really strange that it would stop working because the cable isn't attached.  I tried to reboot without the cable plugged into the Pi to confirm it wasn't just some sort of glitch when I unplug it while it's running but it will only work if the wired cable is attached first.

Here's a copy of my /etc/network/interfaces file...

```
        auto lo

    iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
            address 10.0.42.111
            network 10.0.42.0
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            broadcast 10.0.42.255
            gateway 10.0.42.1

    allow-hotplug wlan0
    auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet static
            address 10.0.42.112
            network 10.0.42.0
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            broadcast 10.0.42.255
            gateway 10.0.42.1

    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Maybe you think it's using wlan0 but in actual fact it's using eth0?

Comment: No, it's using the wlan.  I can ping both IP and VNC works on both IP.  When the cable is unplugged wlan goes down too.

Comment: I still don't understand why you know it's using wlan0?

Comment: I'm going to move this over to [Su] as I think you will have more luck there. I hope this is okay with you.

Comment: I have two network connections on the Pi and both are staticly assigned. wlan0 is staticly addressed with 10.0.42.112 and the eth0 is set to 10.0.42.111.  If you ping 10.0.42.112 you get a responce.  Hence 10.0.42.112(wlan0) is working.

Comment: Same configuration, my wifi router (Netgear dg834g) reports eth0 mac address in "attached devices" (and eth0 not connected to the router but directly to my PC).

Comment: Use `allow hot-plug xxx` **or** `auto xxx`, but not both for an adapter.   I use `allow hot-plug xxx` for both eth0 and wlan0, both work when connected (cabled for eth0, ssid present for wlan0, as expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same issue, DHCP but the same WLAN0 failure until ETH0 was UP.  In my case @Jivings is correct.  When you ping the receiving response is via ETH0.

Now this goes against everything I understand but in my case with the RPI ethernet cable plugged in :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:b0:0c:39  
          inet addr:192.168.99.75  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:82:33:24  
          inet addr:192.168.99.78  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Take note of the HWaddr on each card.

Then from another workstation, in this case I'm using NMAP :

```
$ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.99.75  **<< - ETH0**

Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-03 10:19 GMT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.99.75
Host is up (0.020s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:B0:0C:39 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
Paul@lo-mbp-preg / $ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.99.78

$ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.99.78  **<< - ETH0**

Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-02-03 10:19 GMT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.99.78
Host is up (0.0044s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:B0:0C:39 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

You can see that the MAC Address/HWAddr for both ETH0 and WLAN0 is the same, and matches the ETH0 HWAddr from ifconfig.  So in my case the Wireless was not working.  All traffic was passing via ETH0

If you don't have NMAP ping and then displaying the ARP table (IP <-> MAC table) will show the same information.  From CLI:

- Windows = *arp -a*
- Linux = *arp*

I actually didnt find 'the reason' for this.  In the process of debugging it started working reliably.  Which I hate.  But this config is now working :

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
        ssid="<ssid>"
        psk=<key>
}
network={
        ssid="<ssid>"
        psk=<key>
}
network={
        ssid="<ssid>"
        psk=<key>
}
network={
        ssid="<ssid>"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        pairwise=TKIP
        group=TKIP
        eap=PEAP
        identity="user@domain"
        password="xxxxxxxxxx"
        ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
        phase1="peapver=0"
        phase2="MSCHAPV2"
}
```

I hope this helps you make some progress ..

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Will try looking at it again this weekend.

Comment: Ok, found it : bad wpa-psk parameter in interfaces file.

Comment: I just solved this problem for myself.  The issue was caused by something called the "ARP Flux problem."  Basically, when you have a device with 2 interfaces connected to the same network, the same interface can respond to both arp requests and the other machine's arp tables can get screwed up...   This is really hard to debug because the problem isn't always on that device, IE arp caching on the router or other machines.

Answer (score 2):

You may try look what "route -n" gives you before and after you unplug the cable. If eth0 goes down it removes the default route. Therefore you need to create a new default route associated with wlan0. Add this into your eth0 section of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
pre-up if [ `ip route show|grep default|wc -l` -eq 1 ];then route del default gw xx.xx.xx.xx dev wlan0;fi
post-down if [ `ip route show|grep wlan0|wc -l` -eq 1 ];then route add default gw xx.xx.xx.xx dev wlan0;fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue with Debian Jessie on my Raspberry Pi. Turned out I forgot to install the `wpasupplicant` package. Use the following command to check installed packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep wpa
```

This should at least list package `wpasupplicant`. If not, install it:

```
apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Then, calculate the correct WPA PSK hash for your SSID (replace `<myssid>` and `<passphrase>` accordingly):

```
wpa_passphrase <myssid> <passphrase>
```

This outputs a few lines. We only need the 64 characters hash value. Open `interfaces` file:

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

...and add the SSID and the hash:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myssid
    wpa-psk e71e118835ca1d72c61db51b9a0687df088f4952c27760cd2da05cfb2f3dad33
```

Save your changes and restrict access to this file to prevent pre-shared key (PSK) disclosure:

```
chmod 600 /etc/network/interfaces
```

It might be useful to add `wpa-debug-level 3` to the `interfaces` file: this writes a lot of debug messages to the log file `/var/log/syslog`.

Further instruction can be found at: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse (section "wpa_supplicant").

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although checking the MAC addresses I could find that my SSH connections were performed through the right devices. Nonetheless I couldn't SSH to `wlan0` if `eth0` was down.

I solved it by setting static DHCP assignments in my router. Now I have both interfaces working independently and the IP addresses I wanted to have in each of them (I didn't even change the `interfaces` file to set the configuration to `iface XXX inet dhcp`)

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly identical symptoms. Discovered a bad interaction between my router (Tomato) and my rpi.  Turning off APSD on the router made the problem go away.